# clearInterval won't stop setInterval

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this piece of game for a bricks game in javascript. The thing is that my clearInterval function doesn't want to stop even if it's globally declared. I added here my draw function which renders the canvas each time when that setInterval is called.

```
initbricks();
draw();
init_mouse();
var i = setInterval(draw,100);  

function play(){    
    document.getElementById("play").disabled = true;
}     

function reset(){
    clear();
    clearInterval(i);
}

//Initialize game
function init() {
    document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", play);
    document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", reset);
}

//Load canvas after window has loaded
if (document.getElementById) window.onload=init;

function draw() {
    clear();
    circle(ballX,ballY,radius);  
    rect(paddlex, height-paddleh, paddlew, paddleh);

    //draw bricks
    for (i=0; i < NROWS; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = rowcolors[i];  
        for (j=0; j < NCOLS; j++) {
            if (bricks[i][j] == 1) {
                rect((j * (BRICKWIDTH + PADDING)) + PADDING, 
                     (i * (BRICKHEIGHT + PADDING)) + PADDING,
                     BRICKWIDTH, BRICKHEIGHT);
            }
        }
    }

    // hit brick?
    rowheight = BRICKHEIGHT + PADDING;
    colwidth = BRICKWIDTH + PADDING;
    row = Math.floor(ballY/rowheight);
    col = Math.floor(ballX/colwidth);
    // if so, reverse the ball and mark the brick as broken
    if (ballY<NROWS*rowheight && row>=0 && col>=0 && bricks[row][col]==1) {
        dy = -dy;
        bricks[row][col] = 0;
    }

    // if game not over, move paddle
    if (ballY+dy<height)
        if (rightDown && paddlex+paddlew<width)
            paddlex += 5;
        else if (leftDown && paddlex>0)
            paddlex -= 5;

    // Right/Left stop condition
    if (ballX+dx>width-5 || ballX+dx<5)
        dx= -dx;

    // Up stop condition
    if (ballY+dy<5)
        dy= -dy;

    // Down stop condition
    else 
        //i f ball is on the paddle
        if (ballY+dy>height-20 && ballX>paddlex && ballX<paddlex+paddlew) 
            dy= -dy;

    // if ball is not on the paddle
    else if (ballY+dy>height+20){
        // game over, so stop the animation
        clearInterval(i);
    }                                                 
    ballX += dx;
    ballY += dy;
}
```

Comment: What is the output on the console?

Comment: For instance, the content of `draw` could be pretty important here. Also note that you have no `clear` function shown; if an error occurs calling `clear` (because it doesn't exist) or within `clear` (if it exists but just isn't shown above), `clearInterval` will never be called.

Comment: Possibly the value of `i` is being overwritten somewhere, before `clearInterval` is called.

Comment: Please see update above. My clear function is working but after the canvas is cleared, the ball keeps on going, so the clearInterval is not called at all!

Comment: did u use the variable `i` elsewhere? since `i` is a pretty common variable name

Comment: why not use a different variable besides `i` for your `setInterval()` timer var

Comment: Thanks mate! That was it, i was used before:)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i=0; i < NROWS; i++) {
```

it seems that variable `i` has been replaced by the `for` loop.

Rename your interval variable name

Answer (score 2):

You've got multiple variables called `i`, and the one in the `draw` function hasn't been given a `var` declaration specifier so it's overwriting your timer variable.

In any event (pun not intended) you should investigate `window.requestAnimationFrame` to handle your screen refreshes, and not use timers at all.  It'll make your game animation much smoother.